# How to fix Numpy REFS_OK flag error?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread('pic1.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

height = 0
count = 0
it = np.nditer(image)
for(x) in it:
      count += 1
      if count == 80:
             count = 0
             height += 1
      if x > 400:
             print("Height is: " + height)
             break
```

When I try to run the code I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Iterator operand or requested dtype holds references, but the REFS_OK flag was not enabled
```

Why do I get this error? When I tried looking it up it seems like people just work around it instead of fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the returned `image` variable isn't `None`.
Perhaps the image is not in the path your script is run from.
OpenCV doesn't raise an exception when it can't read/load the image, but, rather, returns `None`, in which case weird exceptions you will meet, when you try to operate on that `None`... like the exception posted.

(Sorry for speaking like Yoda... :-) )

Comment: How would I do that? This is my first time working with Python or OpenCV.